# "expected an expression" error, when I type in the exact same code as ive seen someone else do an they didnt get the error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to learn C++20, but ive quickly run into an error "expected an expression"
when I type in the exact same as the one in the youtube video, but they are not getting that error.

the code is

```
#include <iostream> 

int main(){
    auto result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;   
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

what im getting an error on is the (10 <=> 20) part, but they wrote it the exact same way on the video, and I cant find any information or video anywhere that helps me solve this problem.

Comment: It's likely that the compiler or linter you're using doesnt know about the spaceship `<=>` operator. You probably need a more up to date extension or compiler, or maybe a compiler flag for C++20 support.

Comment: I imagine the default C++ in vscode doesnt know about spaceship operator. So that's why I think you need a C++ extension that supports C++20.

Comment: Or rather a vscode extension

Comment: it says expected an expression C/C++ (29)   if thats any help, but the brackets () are red, and they are red when i type them, and thats before I type the space ship thing, i dont know if thats the same problem. i have downloaded the exact same compiler at the guy on youtube so i would think that is not that, but if it is, how would i fix that? what extension could help with this? i cant finda any extensions that add support for c++20

Comment: does it compile, yes, then it is an intellisense problem/setting. Get a C++20 compatible compiler.

Comment: I found that i needed to go to VIEW>Command Palette>C/C++:Edit Configurations (UI)  and then scroll down to the bottom and change from C++17 to C++20. now i dont have the errors anymore, Thank you guys SO MUCH for the help, I can finally start learning C++ now:)

Comment: You're welcome to add an answer to your own question @jimandre